# Estimate $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x)dx$ using lower and upper sums

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $f:[0,\pi/2]\to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=\sin (x)$.
Using the standard partition $P_n$ of $[0, \pi/2]$ with $n$ equal subintervals, evaluate $L(f, P_n)$ and $U(f, P_n)$. Deduce that $f$ is integrable, and evaluate $\int_0^{\pi/2} f(x)dx$.

I know that the value of this integral is $1$, but I don't know how to calculate the sums. I know their rules well but can't calculate them for $\sin(x)$.

Comment: If you don't mind I'm going to put this in a more formal format. I suggest that you learn LaTeX as it will improve your writing skills.

Comment: Note that $\sin(x)$ is increasing on $[0,\pi/2]$. This means that the lower sum is actually the left sum, and the upper sum is actually the right sum. Do you know how to write down the left and right sums for a given partition?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I calculated the minimum and maximum of each partition but can't continue.. for example minimum for the subinterval [Xi-1, Xi] is (πi - π)/2n and the maximum is πi/2n, and I know the formula of lower sum and upper sum but can't do more calculations because I can't deal with sin((πi-π)/2n) for example. I'm just a beginner in Riemann integration.

Comment: hmmm... I suppose the better question is what have you proved about $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions? Do you have that $\sin(x)$ is monotone? If so we know it's Riemann integrable. Rather it can be easily proved that it is, depending on what theorems are available to you.

Comment: Also if you're having issues with an evenly parsed interval, why not try say a geometric interval? where $P_n:=\{0,a_i=\pi \frac{1}{2^i}:1<i \leq n\}$?

Comment: One reason not to use a geometric interval is that the problem says to use "the standard partition", which is presumably a division into equal length subintervals.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly
$$ P_n=\{x_i: x_i=\frac{i\pi}{2n}, i=0,1,\cdots,n \}. $$
Noting that $f(x)=\sin x$ is increasing in $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, hence one has
$$ M_i=\max_{i}\{f(x): x_{i-1}\le x\le x_i\}=f(x_i)=\sin x_i, $$
and $$ m_i=\min_{i}\{f(x): x_{i-1}\le x\le x_i\}=f(x_{i-1})=\sin x_{i-1}.$$
So
\begin{eqnarray}
U(f,P_n)&=&\sum_{i=1}^nM_i(x_i-x_{i-1})=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\sin x_i,\\
L(f,P_n)&=&\sum_{i=1}^nm_i(x_i-x_{i-1})=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\sin x_{i-1},
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$ U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n)=\frac{\pi}{2n}\sum_{i=1}^n(\sin x_i-\sin x_{i-1})=\frac{\pi}{2n}\sin x_n=\frac{\pi}{2n}. $$
Thus for $\forall \epsilon>0$, there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{\pi}{2n}<\epsilon$ and hence
$$ U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n)<\epsilon. $$
Namely $f(x)=\sin x$ is integrable. Since
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\to\infty}U(f,P_n)&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{2n}\sum_{i=1}^n\sin x_i\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{2n}\sum_{i=1}^n\sin \frac{i\pi}{2n}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{2n}\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\sin[(1+\frac1n)\frac{\pi}{4}]}{\sin\frac{\pi}{4n}}\\
&=&1,
\end{eqnarray}
so
$$ \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin xdx=1. $$